# Error "Bad format of conversation ID"(skype) when send message from skype to direct

Tags: c#, botframework

Why I have error `Bad format of conversation ID`(skype) when send message from skype to direct.

```
IMessageActivity msg = context.MakeMessage();
msg.ChannelId = user.ChannelId;
msg.ServiceUrl = user.serviceUrl;
msg.Recipient = new ChannelAccount(id: user.userID);
msg.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: user.conversationId);
msg.Text = textMsg.Text; await context.PostAsync(msg);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking the API documentation?

Comment: What is the value of `user.conversationId` at run time? Maybe it's not in the required format...

Comment: either way, this question doesn't have enough info to answer and should be put on hold

Comment: What is the value of user.conversationId at run time? It saved conversationId. I don't understand, why when I send message from skype to skype or from direct to webchat, all is right. But skype+direct or skype+ webchat have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use context.send(), I must use

`var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(msg.ServiceUrl), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"]);
            await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)msg);`